# Problems with Java Card, PCSC lite, and Applet Playground

Tags: javacard, apdu, pcsc, globalplatform

I've been trying to get started using Java Card.  I downloaded and installed the repository at this link: https://github.com/martinpaljak/AppletPlayground/ with the hope of starting to develop and use applets, but as of yet I have had no success interacting with the card or reader in any way.  Running

```
 "java -jar lib/openkms-globalplatform.jar -info"
```

at the command line returns nothing - according the the GlobalPLatform site, https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatform , it should return information about the card.  Running "pcsctest" on the command line yields either

```
 "Testing SCardEstablishContext    : Service not available." or 
 "Testing SCardEstablishContext    : Command successful.
 Testing SCardGetStatusChange (and then doesn't do anything until I control Z)"
```

depending on how long it has been since I plugged in the reader.  If I run any command when the `pcsctest` returns "service not available" I get the error

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: PC/SC, provider: JNA2PCSC, class: jnasmartcardio.Smartcardio$JnaTerminalFactorySpi)....
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jnasmartcardio.Smartcardio$JnaPCSCException: SCardEstablishContext got response 0x8010001d (SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE: The Smart card resource manager is not running.).
```

I'm using OS X.  I've tried a couple different tools for interacting with Java Cards and I haven't got any of them to work. I would really appreciate it if somebody could show me what I might be doing wrong or suggest a better way to interact with Java Cards.

Comment: seems to me that your PCSC stack is not up and running, this is likely more an OS X issue. Please try another forum and clearly state your OS and card reader (versions) there.

Comment: @owlstead thanks for the edit, sorry if I posted in the wrong forum.  Could you recommend another forum where my question, or future java card questions, would be better placed?  Since posting the question I realized that my reader's product and vendor IDs were not included in the Info.plist file in the ccid bundle.  I added them and after that pcsctest will progress past where it was stopping when I asked the question.

Comment: Java questions are of course on topic here. This forum is however not the best place to ask about getting a reader to work on a specific operating system. Glad you've proceeded beyond this question, feel free to ask Java Card related questions if you get stuck (preferably after trying some things yourself and checking documentation & for similar questions here of course). Welcome to SO :)